# "How to Tag" pane text z-index is lower than footer

Tags: bug, sidebar

**How to Tag** pane text has a lower `z-index` than footer text, results in really hard to read information when the pane overlaps the footer.

**Edit**
Since this question has been incorrectly marked as duplicate, I will explain the difference. The older question merely points out that the sidebar covers the footer, however my question points out that there's an error with the z-index of the sidebar which makes the sidebar hard to read.

[image]

**Steps:**

1. start creating a new question
2. focus on the **Tags** field
3. scroll down the page until the **How to Tag** pane overlaps the footer
4. observe that the sidebar text and footer text are visible on the same plane rendering the sidebar text illegible

**Suggestion:**

Give the element `#content #sidebar #scroller` a `z-index` of `1`